# Jacobian to Transform Gradient

Tags: differential-geometry

The gradient is considered covariant.  The Jacobian is used to transform covariant vector to another bases.  Why does the definition of gradient transform use metric tensor and not Jacobian? In other words to convert gradient from one base to another, why cant I just use a Jacobian?

Comment: Please provide more context. I never heard that to transform a gradient into another base we use the metric tensor.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the gradient of a function is defined as $\text{grad}(f):=\varphi^{-1}(df)$, where $\varphi^{-1}:T^*M\to TM$ is the isomorphism induced by the metric
$$\varphi:TM\to T^*M\quad\quad v\mapsto g_x(v,\cdot)$$
So, naturally, the transformation rules should involve the transformation rules of the metric tensor.